# Cannot run g++ compiled program Ubuntu

Tags: c++, bash, ubuntu, codeblocks

I created a simple program

```
 #include <cstdio>

int main(){

    printf("Hello world!");

    return 0;
}
```

and compiled it with CodeBlocks 13.12 on Ubuntu 16.04, successfully

I am trying to run it from bash nothing happens

[image]
What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: You should type `./test`

Comment: Thank you! sorry for this stupid question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`test`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html) is an intrinsic bash shell command, so instead of calling your executable program you're calling this one.

To call you own executable `test` refer to the local binary in the directory it was created. Either `./test`, or `~/Programs/test/bin/Release/test`.